# How to change something dynamically in the main handlebars skeleton?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, templating

I am using handelbars as my templating engine and I am curious to whether I could edit the main handlebars file. What I can do at the moment is something like this:

main.handlebars:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='headerBox></div>
    <div id='contents'>{{{body}}}</div><!--all contents goes here-->
  </body>
```

When I use this method I will could create templates e.g. home.handlebars etc.

But what If I wanted to change something dynamically in the main.handlebars? For example in my website, I would love to have a login form so I would like to have something like this in the main.handelbars:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='headerBox>{{If logged in print name, if not print sign up}}</div>
    <div id='contents'>{{{body}}}</div><!--all contents goes here-->
  </body>
</html>
```

TLDR, how to I change something dynamically in the main handlebars skeleton.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write a Handlebars Helper function.  Since you didn't include anything about how you're verifying login, I'll write a little demo.

In your template file:

```
<div id='headerBox'>{{header}}</div>
Handlerbars.registerHelper('header', function() {
   if (loggedIn) {
      return //however you're getting a username
   } else {
      return <a href="/signup.html">Sign Up</a>
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm learning node.js with express at the moment I am using there default system. (E.g main.handlebars goes in the layout folder) and all my subviews go in the views folder. I've only done a bit of php before node.js so I would have something like:
Handlerbars.registerHelper('header', function() {
   if (node.jsSession is set) {
      return username
   } else {
      return <a href="/signup.html">Sign Up</a>
   }
});

How would I incorporate this in node.js with express?